# CSS and other Style option not working on github pages

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

So, I'm doing a test for a job opportunity, and one of the challenges was to develop a website to show how I'm programming sites. I did the site, used some javascript components to add a carousel, a sidebar, and other cool addons, along with bootstrap.
The opportunity said that the site needs to be upload at GitHub pages, so i uploaded all my files (all the .js, .css, index.html, and images) to the main branch and did a pull request to the GH-pages branch. But when I opened the link, the CSS, javascript, and other stuff don't seem to work. How can I fix this?
PS: Do the site only using html+css isn't an option now due time to deliver the site.

How it should look:
[image]

How it is looking in the GitHub pages link:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a [mcve] or a link to your GH pages? It's hard to say what the problem is without your code. My guess is that you have some relative/absolute links to your JS/CSS assets that only work locally.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably your file isn't loading. Check console to see if there is an error. It gets sometimes to load `js` files on GitHub pages. Try reloading the page.